# Can .net apps run side by side a WCF service site?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, ascx

In other words is it possible to host aspx and ascx files inside the same IIS site running svc files?

Comment: Did you try this before asking? :/

Comment: Hit an error with one of my ascx files, needed to drop and recreate it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yep.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.  IIS treats the svc files just like an aspx page and hands processing off to another module. I have a few sites running this way.